# HTML/CSS scrolling menu is covered the content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this website: http://ahmad2020.accountsupport.com/

It's a one-page WordPress website where you can click on the menu and then it will scroll to the corresponding section.

Now, It's covered the content when I jumped to that corresponding section.

Like this image also you can check on the live too.

[image]

**The menu is covered the top content.**

But it should be like that:

[image]

If I use css `margin-top` then the design is breaking because then I can see top blank space.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Share your scroll script

Comment: @user9437856 I am using elementor plugin.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I haven't used elementor. Have you found the solution?

Comment: @user9437856 I have added a class to each section using JS to fix it.

Comment: Cool. Please add your answer here

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your page this is caused due to the Navbar `position:fixed`
wrap all the below the navbar in a single div and give `margin-top:navbar-height` to fixed this issue

Comment: Let me remove the padding

Comment: I have removed the padding. Now its covered the more content :(

Comment: just do one thing comment the code of navbar position:fixed and click on the id it will work as expected but navbar will not scroll.

Comment: you need to wrap the content below the navbar in a single div and give them margin-top as your navbar to fix